# Docker container export and deployement question

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I got a question - I have a docker image running locally on my Mac. - I'm trying to export that local image and deploy on AWS elasticbean stalk env.

Should I use docker export command which outputs it as a tar file then upload to AWS? or should it be in a different non compressed format?

I already tried the above and docker export it as a tar file but AWS didn't like that so what approach should I take here?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a repository in your aws ECR (Amazon Elastic Container Registry) and push your local image to that repo

```
aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-2
docker tag test-pod:latest 24533xxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/test:latest
docker push 24533xxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/test:latest
```